# How to view data from inner join with friendly view in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

i want to create some simple system for my production which is they can scan bar-code on product and the system can view the JIT that they can use for paste the label on that product. Some of product must use 2 JIT for paste the label and some of JIT can be used on many product. I have create 3 table in mysql which is 'product','jit' and 'production_jit' with many to many relation.

[image: Table]

i was created the inner join to pull the data from MySQL by using product number.

```
$code = $_POST['code'];




    $sql = "SELECT product.product_number,product.product_name,product.product_jitqty,product.product_desc,jit.jit_number,jit.jit_name,jit.jit_drawer,jit.jit_port,jit.jit_specpath 
            FROM product 
            JOIN production_jit 
            ON production_jit.product_number = product.product_number 
            JOIN jit 
            ON jit.jit_number = production_jit.jit_number
            WHERE product.product_number = '$code'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 

    {   ?>
                <table>
                <tr><td>Product Number</td><td>: <?php echo $row['product_number']; ?></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Product Name</td><td>: <?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Product Description</td><td>: <?php echo $row['product_desc']; ?></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Product Jit Quantity</td><td>: <?php echo $row['product_jitqty']; ?></td></tr>
                <tr><td>JIT Number</td><td>: <?php echo $row['jit_number']; ?></td></tr>
                <tr><td>JIT Name</td><td>: <?php echo $row['jit_name']; ?></td></tr>
                <tr><td><font color="red">JIT Drawer</font></td><td><font color="red">: <?php echo $row['jit_drawer']; ?></font></td></tr>
                <tr><td><font color="red">JIT Port</font></td><td><font color="red">: <?php echo $row['jit_port']; ?></font></td></tr>
                <tr><td>JIT Spec</td><td>: <?php echo $row['jit_specpath']; ?></td></tr>
                </table>
                <h1><strong>Please scan JIT barcode on JIT</strong></h1>

                <table>
                <form action="product3.php" method="post" name="check2">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="productnumber" value="<?php echo $row['productNumber']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="jitnumber" value="<?php echo $row['jitNumber2']; ?>">
                <tr><td>JIT Barcode</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" name="jitcode" maxlength="200"/></td></tr>
                </table>
                <table>
                <td></td><td colspan="3" align="right"><input name="hantar" type="submit" value="Check"></td>
                </table>

        <?php
    }

    }
    else {
                ?>
                <script>
                alert("Invalid Barcode");
                window.location.href = "product.php";
                </script><?php
            }

            mysqli_close($conn);
```

If the product used only one JIT, the interface look good,but if the Product used 2 JIT, the system show the looping data.

[image: View when 1 product with 2 JIT]

In logic situation, the view is correct, but how can i customize, the repeated data will not show by the system. for this example, only jit table can show in the looping. as the picture below, one product have 2 JIT, so i just to show about product information once, but only JIT Infomation i want to show follow the data..

[image]

Comment: Didn't quite understand the question. You want to write a SQL to only display data from jit table?

Comment: @Erick sorry if my question not clear. what i mean is,if the product have 2 jit, i just want to show _'product number','product name','product description','product jit quantity'_ once because the data is same, but want the _'JIT number',JIT Name',JIT Drawer',JIT port' and 'JIT spec'_ show both data because the data is different..

Answer (score 0):

IF you're saying you only want one of the datasets to show up, just use `break` so only the first dataset will show up:

```
    <?php
    $phead='';
    $pbody='';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 

{  
            if(empty($phead)){
                $phead.='<table>';
                $phead.='<tr><td>Product Number</td><td>: '.$row['product_number'].'</td></tr>';
                $phead.='<tr><td>Product Name</td><td>: '.$row['product_name'].'</td></tr>';
                $phead.='<tr><td>Product Description</td><td>: '.$row['product_desc'].'</td></tr>';
                $phead.='<tr><td>Product Jit Quantity</td><td>: '.$row['product_jitqty'].'</td></tr>';
            }
            $pbody.='<tr><td>JIT Number</td><td>: '.$row['jit_number'].'</td></tr>';
            $pbody.='<tr><td>JIT Name</td><td>: '.$row['jit_name'].'</td></tr>';
            $pbody.='<tr><td><font color="red">JIT Drawer</font></td><td><font color="red">: '.$row['jit_drawer'].'</font></td></tr>';
            $pbody.='<tr><td><font color="red">JIT Port</font></td><td><font color="red">: '.$row['jit_port'].'</font></td></tr>';
            $pbody.='<tr><td>JIT Spec</td><td>: '.$row['jit_specpath'].'</td></tr>';

}
//Now, we only have 1 instance of $phead and can have multiple $pbody;
if(!empty($phead)){
    echo $phead;
    echo $pbody;
    echo '</table>';
}

?>
```

I've updated my answer to match your conditions. 1 set of product header information and multiple JIT info.

Comment: thanks @GregBorbonus . i want to show only one set of data but, _JIT number',JIT Name',JIT Drawer',JIT port' and 'JIT spec'_ have 2 data.. how can i set only that column can show more data if they have more than 1 data..?

Comment: thanks @Greg Borbonus.. i  tried and you give me that i want. but... i want to send some data using hiden input from that table.. but the data seem like not post to another page,... i have edit your code with my code.

Comment: why this button not function??

$pbody.='<tr><td> <input type="button" value="Marking Spec" onclick="window.open("'.$row['product_spec'].'")" /></td></tr>';